# pytest: multiple tests were failed if run together but success when run one by one

Tags: pytest, fastapi

I'm testing the endpoint that created via fastApi. The tests that failing are all come from the endpoint that need to query the parameters, please see the example below

BTW: I'm using the TestClient from fastApi

Example 1

```
def test_fetch_paged_ggci_is_success():
    page = 2
    page_limit = 15 

    page_endpoint = "ggci/list?page={}&limit={}".format(page, page_limit)
    response = client.get(page_endpoint, headers=headers)
    fetched_page = response.json()
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert len(fetched_page) == page_limit
```

Example 2

```
def test_increase_limits_of_the_paged_ggci_shall_not_influnce_fetch_order():
    page = 1
    page_limit = 10
    page_endpoint = "ggci/list?page={}&limit={}".format(page, page_limit)

    page_limit_increased = 15
    page_endpoint_limit_increased = "ggci/list?page={}&limit={}".format(page, page_limit_increased)

    response = client.get(page_endpoint, headers=headers)
    response_limitresponse = client.get(page_endpoint, headers=headers)response = client.get(page_endpoint, headers=headers)_increased = client.get(page_endpoint_limit_increased, headers=headers)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response_limit_increased.status_code == 200

    fetched_page = response.json()
    fetched_page_limit_increased = response_limit_increased.json()
    assert len(fetched_page) == page_limit
    assert len(fetched_page_limit_increased) == page_limit_increased
```

If running the test like the one above individually, it pass without issue. But when running the test all together only the first one passed.

I think they are interfering each-other. when `response = client.get(page_endpoint, headers=headers)` is called in each function. A function might picked up other function's `page_endpoint` .How can I segregate each test to run individually?

Comment: Your first test does not have anything referencing `page_endpoint`, but attempts to reference that name inside it. Are you sure this test is actually correct?

Comment: Fixed, I changed all the function name and some of the variable names, I don't want to leak the code base. But you are right, this is an error due to that